# Extended ASCII table issues on a 64-bit OS

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, ascii, character-set

Consider:

[image]

Our old 32-bit program using the US-ASCII extended table (128-256) to create simple borders for its program menus.

For example, decimal 193 is an upside down Tee.

However, when the program is installed on a Windows 10 64-bit OS, the ASCII extended table is surpassed by ISO-8859-1 (Latin) character set.

Is there a solution to this borders graphic issue when running on a 64-bit OS?

Comment: Change the 32-bit app to specify the font.

Answer (score 1):

The old symbols are part of [Code Page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437). You can change your active using [CHCP](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) before you run your program.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround I have used is to download and install a copy of DOSBOX available from https://www.dosbox.com/download.php?main=1

Setting it up is a little complex, but it will report a DOS version 5.

Use it to create the frames and borders that you need, then save the file with a .txt extension.

Move the file to a directory of your choice, rename it and keep it as a template.

You can then open it in your favourite editor - to create the menu that you require, then save it with the .bat extension.

NOTE: The frame and border characters may not appear the same as when you created them in DOSBOX - but they should appear as normal when you run the batch file with the menu in it.

Answer (score -1):

You could specify to Windows that the program should be run in compatibility mode
on an old version of Windows:

- Right-click the program's `.exe`
- Choose Properties
- Go to the Compatibility tab
- Under Compatibility mode, check "Run this program in compatibility mode for:"
- In the drop-down list, choose an old Windows version
- Click OK

Comment: Thanks to your ideas we were able to determine that the font could be changed within the application. We were able to instal  TTF MS Draw and even make it scalable. Any recommendation for other TTF.

Comment: Someone downvoted an answer that worked for the poster. Really?